# How to create a random variable to be used as another variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of variables that hold specific links to sites. I want to set a variable to open a random one but whenever I set 'randvid' it becomes a string rather than the variable that I want to use. Here's an example of my code:

```
import random
import webbrowser

vid1 = 'link1'
vid2 = 'link2'
vid3 = 'link3'

n = random.randint(1,3)
randvid = 'vid' + str(n)
webbrowser.open_new(randvid)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a bunch of variables ending in ordered numbers, you should probably be using a list instead.

Comment: you can not access variables by name like you think/try to. use a list instead and pull one item out of the list:  `random.choice([vid1,vid2,vid3])` like  datawrestler suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use random.choice here:

```
random.choice([vid1, vid2, vid3])
```

The documentation can be located [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) but basically, it selects a random item from a sequence, such as a list. By constructing a list out of your defined variable options, you can select an item at random using random.choice.

If you need to be able to reproduce your results, you can combine random.choice with random.seed:

```
random.seed(1000)

random.choice([vid1, vid2, vid3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a list and store theses three variables of links in the list and call function `random.choice(lst)` and store value in a variable.
Here is complete code.

```
import random
import webbrowser
vid1 = 'link1'
vid2 = 'link2'
vid3 = 'link3'
lst=[vid1,vid2,vid3]
var = random.choice(lst)
webbrowser.open_new(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we no need to create so many variables as per me.

just put all links in list

```
mylinks =['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
```

select random index

```
n = random.randint(0, len(mylinks))
```

select n index from list

```
webbrowser.open_new(mylinks[n])
```